# How to drop null values from dynamic loop generated from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe, python-itertools

I have a data-frame like this:

```
   ORDER_NO         2401        2504         2600
    2020020         2019-12-04  2019-12-10   2019-12-12 
    2020024         2019-12-25  NaN          2019-12-20
    2020034         NaN         NaN          2019-12-20
    2020020         2019-12-12  2019-12-15   2019-12-18
```

I am creating XML from the above data-frame. I want remove the null value being populated into the XML.
My code should drop that particular column and row value from XML.

**My code**

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>"""

cols = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        for c, r in zip(row[2:], cols[1:]):
            f.write(body.format(r, c))
```

**Current output for record 2**

```
<ORD>2020024</ORD>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="2401">
<DTM>2019-12-25</DTM>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="2504">
<DTM>NaN</DTM>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="2600">
<DTM>2019-12-20</DTM>
```

**Expected output for record 2**

```
 <ORD>2020024</ORD>
    <osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="2401">
    <DTM>2019-12-25</DTM>
    <osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="2600">
    <DTM>2019-12-20</DTM>
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `stack`

Naturally drops the nulls

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>"""

for o, d in df.set_index('ORDER_NO').stack().groupby('ORDER_NO'):
    with open(f'{o}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(o))
        for (o, s), date in d.iteritems():
            f.write(body.format(s, date))
```

---

#### Details

```
df.set_index('ORDER_NO').stack()

ORDER_NO      
2020020   2401   2019-12-04
          2504   2019-12-10
          2600   2019-12-12
2020024   2401   2019-12-25
          2600   2019-12-20
2020034   2600   2019-12-20
2020020   2401   2019-12-12
          2504   2019-12-15
          2600   2019-12-18
```

---

#### BTW

Your solution would be fine with an `if`

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>"""

cols = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        for c, r in zip(row[2:], cols[1:]):
            if pd.notna(c):
                f.write(body.format(r, c))
```

Comment: I just added a footer (`footer = """<END>123</END>""`) but output is coming in the same line `<DTM>2020-03-29</DTM><END>123</END>` instead of new line.

Comment: When you use `f.write` it doesn't assume to put an `'\n'` for you.  You got those form your `body` string.  Specify your footer with `footer = """\n<END>123</END>"""`